# Problem with properly positioning enemies in a space invaders game

Tags: c#, winforms, game-physics

I'm in a bit of a pickle with a piece of code. I want to put 30 enemies which are PictureBoxes, in 6 rows by 5. But what ends up happening is it draws only 1 row of them. I want the objects to e in a 6x5 grid, their size is 50x50 so i've tried to make the point draw every 60 pixels.

```
    public void Enemy()
        {
            PictureBox[] enemy = new PictureBox[30];
            for (int i = 0; i <6; i++)
            {
                for(int k =0; k < 5;k++)
                {
                    enemy[k] = new PictureBox();
                    enemy[k].Image = Properties.Resources.rsz_invader;
                    enemy[k].Size = new Size(50, 50);
                    enemy[k].Tag = "enemy";
                    enemy[k].Location = new Point(k*60,i * 60);
                }
            }
            this.Controls.AddRange(enemy);
        }
```

Comment: The variable `enemy` needs to be a two-dimensional array or an array of arrays. Right now each row overwrites the previous row.

Comment: Your enemy array only use the first 5 positions. The k variable only take the values 0 to 4.

Comment: @JohnWu i understand, i'll try a two-dimensional array. Reading your comment actually made me realise what was actually going on. Thank you.

Comment: You should 'cache' the enemy image in an image variable and use that over and over.  As is you are creating a new image object for each slot.  This is wasteful and if you delete the control when the invader dies, your app will likely leak.  The same goes for the picture boxes - consider toggling visibility rather can creating new ones.